# How to test which strings from File A are not present in File B, without displaying anything that is present in File B and not in File A?

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep

I have a text file, say sitelist1.txt (File A), that has some URLs like below:

```
http://www.facebook.com
http://www.twitter.com
http://myspace.com/profile
http://orkut.com/archived
```

I have another text file, say sitelist2.txt (File B), that has numerous existing URLs.

I tried:

```
fgrep -v -f sitelist1.txt sitelist2.txt
```

The problem is - This also displays the URLs that are present in sitelist2.txt and not in sitelist1.txt

Comment: I think removing the `-v` will get you what you want.

Comment: I want to see only those URLs from sitelist1.txt that are not present on sitelist2.txt.

Comment: In that case, the order of files in your `grep` is incorrect. It should be `fgrep -v -f sitelist2.txt sitelist1.txt` Also, your question is unclear as to which file is fileA and which is fileB. I suggest you edit it to clarify that.

Answer (score 3):

The `-v` you passed is making it do the opposite of what you intend - it is showing you, for each line in `sitelist1.txt`, all lines in `sitelist2.txt` that are not matches. So you're seeing a lot of duplicates, I would bet. You want to use the same command without the `-v` option:

```
fgrep -f sitelist1.txt sitelist2.txt
```

That will execute the following english directive: For each line in `sitelist1.txt`, show me all lines in `sitelist2.txt` that contain the file 1 line I'm interested in, as the entire line or as part of the file 2 line.

The `-v` option is an "invert match" option, which shows you all non-matching lines.

Comment: I am interested to see only those URLs from sitelist1.txt that are not present on sitelist2.txt. Maybe I should reframe the question.

Comment: Updated the question. Want to see which strings from sitelist1.txt are not present in sitelist2.txt.

Answer (score 2):

John's answer (beside the misunderstanding pointed out in the comments under the question) is the answer to the question, however I'd like to also point out that for simple operations like this one `combine` (part of [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/)) is a good choice; it's very easy to use as it allows to express the operation to be done using boolean operators (AND, OR, NOT and XOR supported):

```bsh
combine sitelist1.txt NOT sitelist2.txt
```

```bsh
% cat sitelist1.txt 
http://www.facebook.com
http://www.twitter.com
http://myspace.com/profile
http://orkut.com/archived
% cat sitelist2.txt 
http://www.facebook.com
http://www.twitter.com
http://myspace.com/profile
% combine sitelist1.txt NOT sitelist2.txt
http://orkut.com/archived
```

Contrarily to most utilities the input files *don't* need to be sorted (though I'd guess they're still sorted internally), however as when using `fgrep` there is a pitfall in case of duplicate lines in `sitelist1.txt` that one doesn't want to be printed. If `sitelist1.txt` contains duplicate lines and you don't want to print them you'll have to pipe `combine`'s output to `sort -u`:

```bsh
combine sitelist1.txt NOT sitelist2.txt | sort -u
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for complete urls in each line and not substrings, you could use `comm`

`comm -23 <(sort -u fileA) <(sort -u fileB)`

Explanation:
comm expects sorted input, so we first sort and unique-fy the 2 files `(sort -u file)`.
Next - use process substitution to pass the output of `sort -u` as a "file" to comm, since comm expects files: `comm <() <()`.
Last - suppress columns 2 (lines unique to file B) and 3 (lines common to both files) to output only lines in column 1 (lines unique to file A).